# c# - Share Registry Data between Users

Tags: c#, registry

I've got some Data which I need to share between my Windows Service (running as separate User) and my Application running as currently logged User.
Both Service and Application may use Admin Rights. Which is the best Place in Registry to write that Data?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you need to use registry? Or is the registry you first idea that popped up? (I personally hate the registry ;) )

Comment: It's the first one :)
Any better Ideas?

Comment: WCF contains a few different ways of doing IPC.

Comment: It's not about WCF. It's about Windows Services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the Registry to store some information, you could put the information in the HKLM, if the service account and logged in users will have access to the Key.